# Axios.post() with fs.readFile()/fs.writeFile()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fs

I am receiving a post request from my client, am i am editing a JSON file that is stored locally in the server

```
const dataPath = './data.json';
```

above is my datapath

```
app.post('/table', (req, res) => { // CREATE
        const id = req.body.params.id
        console.log("reqid", id)
        rowdata = req.body.params.userdata
        console.log("rowdata", rowdata)

        fs.readFile(dataPath, "utf-8", function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log("axios post", data)
        })
});
```

above is the code in my post request. When the readFile function is commented out like this:

```
app.post('/table', (req, res) => { // CREATE
            const id = req.body.params.id
            console.log("reqid", id)
            rowdata = req.body.params.userdata
            console.log("rowdata", rowdata)

            //fs.readFile(dataPath, "utf-8", function(err, data){
                //if(err){
                  //  console.log(err)
               // }
               // console.log("axios post", data)
           // })
    });
```

I am able to start the development server, and i am able to run my client and server concurrently

```
> backendserver@1.0.0 dev /Users/Dustyik/Desktop/BTApp
> concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

[0] 
[0] > backendserver@1.0.0 server /Users/Dustyik/Desktop/BTApp
[0] > nodemon server.js
[0] 
[1] 
[1] > backendserver@1.0.0 client /Users/Dustyik/Desktop/BTApp
[1] > npm start --prefix client
[1] 
[0] [nodemon] 2.0.2
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[1] 
[1] > store@0.1.0 start /Users/Dustyik/Desktop/BTApp/client
[1] > set PORT=3002 && react-scripts start
```

However, when the readFile function isnt commented out, i am unable to run the server and client concurrently and my terminal throws me and error

```
[0] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001
[0]     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1306:16)
[0]     at listenInCluster (net.js:1354:12)
[0]     at Server.listen (net.js:1442:7)
[0]     at Function.listen (/Users/Dustyik/Desktop/BTApp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dustyik/Desktop/BTApp/server.js:20:5)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
[0]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
[0] Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
[0]     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1333:8)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
[0]   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
[0]   errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
[0]   syscall: 'listen',
[0]   address: '::',
[0]   port: 3001
[0] }
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.74/
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/Dustyik/Desktop/BTApp/client/public
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
[1] Starting the development server...
```

How can i read(and write) a file in my axios.post() request? am i missing something here?

Edit: my client is currently operating a proxy on port 3001

Answer (score 0):

You see that error because you have another project using the same port 3001

Search for the process using that port with

```
sudo lsof -i :3001
```

and then kill the process

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: Clavjio its because my client is operating a proxy on port 3001, and i am running my server and client concurrently

Comment: just change the port you use on your project to other different than 3001

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the port is changing from the first set of logs to the second set of logs. Notice in the first it shows port 3002 and it works but in the second it shows port 3001. The second one says that "address already in use" and I'm pretty sure it's referring to the port. I would try making sure the port you start your server on is not in use by setting it to use 3002 since that's what seemed to work in the first one.

Comment: its because my client is operating a proxy on port 3001, and im running my server and client concurrently